# Getting error while adding category Magento2

Tags: magento2, category

I am getting below error while saving category.
**This error are from log file.**

> [2019-01-18 12:03:51] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'a76e6b4a_demo.amasty_xsearch_category_fulltext_cl' doesn't exist,
>   query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`
>   (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id`
>   = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`) {"exception":"[object]
>   (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table
>   'a76e6b4a_demo.amasty_xsearch_category_fulltext_cl' doesn't exist,
>   query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`
>   (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id`
>   = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`) at
>
> **/chroot/home/a76e6b4a/buildersbook.com/html/demo/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235,**
>   PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not
>   found: 1146 Table 'a76e6b4a_demo.amasty_xsearch_category_fulltext_cl'
>   doesn't exist at
>   **/chroot/home/a76e6b4a/buildersbook.com/html/demo/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"}**
>   []

**I have installed Amasty Xsearch extension before which I already removed and have been executed below commands too.**

```
rm -rf var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento cache:flush
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento indexer:reset
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**I also give below permissions to my files and folders:**

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: looks like you should contact them since this is a paid extension.

Comment: @Marius My support is expired :(

Comment: @Marius After removing extension why I get this error I dont know. could you help me please

Comment: maybe there is a trigger that remained on the `catalog_category_entity_varchar` from that extension: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/managing-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: Amasty isn't that tight with support periods (in our case). Just give it a try contacting them. Very nice folks over there!

Answer (score 2):

You have added prefix to your database tables 'a76e6b4a_demo' and in Amasty module table name is written statically so it is throwing an error.
You can use below code for table names:

```
$resource is an object of Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection

$this->_resource = $resource; 

$connection=$this->_resource->getConnection(); 

$tableName=$connection->getTableName(YOUR_TABLENAME); // It will return "TablePrefix_YOUR_TABLENAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didnt installed the Amasty Extension properly. Are you installing it through composer ? If so check if your version is community / enterprise .

Do a composer remove of the current one

```
composer remove amasty/xsearch --clear-static-content
```

(check if it has dependencies)

- For community

  composer config repositories.amasty composer https://composer.amasty.com/community/

  composer require amasty/xsearch
- For Enterprise

  composer config repositories.amasty composer https://composer.amasty.com/enterprice/

  composer require amasty/xsearch

Comment: Yes, I have already installed it using composer.